# Code Efficiency: Iterations and Queries

Tags: sql, vb.net, collections, iteration, performance

The code below does a few things:

- Iterates through a colleciton of labels I have on my Windows form, used as a placeholder
- While iterating through the collection, the code is connecting to an SQL database to return a result from a query for each label (about 104 labels)
- Finally some charts are populates.

I have timed this whole process and it takes about 4 or 5 seconds. My goal is to have this process performed instantly or 1 seconds or less.

Could an expert out there explain to me what I'm doing wrong and why this process takes so long?

here is the query:

```vb
Dim RESULT1 As Decimal 'declare this as global

Dim RESULT2 As Decimal 'declare this as global

Private Sub Week(ByVal week As Integer)

    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT " & _
    " (SELECT CAST(SUM(TARGET_SECONDS) AS DECIMAL)/ CAST(SUM(ROUTE_SECONDS) AS DECIMAL) FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE ACTIVE = 1 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME = '" &  cbEmployeeName.Text & "') AS RESULT1," & _
    " (SELECT (SELECT CAST(COUNT(APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID) AS DECIMAL) FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN AS RESULT2 WHERE ACTIVE = 1 AND APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID= 1 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME = '" & cbEmployeeName.Text & "' )/(SELECT CAST(COUNT(APE_BUSDRIVER_STATUS_OBJID) AS DECIMAL) FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN AS RESULT2 WHERE ACTIVE = 1 AND EMPLOYEE_NAME = '" & cbEmployeeName.Text & "' )) AS RESULT2" & _
    " FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE WEEK_TIME = " & week & " AND APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND EMPLOYEE_NAME = '" & cbEmployeeName.Text & "' AND YEAR_TIME = '" & cbYear.Text & "' AND ACTIVE = 1"


    Using connection As New SqlConnection(SQLConnectionStr)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        connection.Open()

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

        ' Call Read before accessing data. 
        If reader.HasRows Then
            While reader.Read()
                RESULT1 = reader("RESULT1")
                RESULT2 = reader("RESULT2")
            End While
        Else
            RESULT1 = 0
            RESULT2 = 0
        End If
        ' Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Here is the code:

```vb
Private Sub LoadWeeklyStats()

    For i As Integer = 0 To 51
        Dim LabelWkEff As String = "LblWkEff" + (i + 1).ToString
        Dim myArray1 As Array = Controls.Find(LabelWkEff, False)
        Dim myControl1 As Label = myArray1(0)
        myControl1.Text = RESULT1
        'AND
        Dim LabelDeliveryStat As String = "lblDeliveryStat" + (i + 1).ToString
        Dim myArray2 As Array = Controls.Find(LabelDeliveryStat, False)
        Dim myControl2 As Label = myArray2(0)
        myControl2.Text = RESULT2
        'COUNTER
        Week(i + 1)
    Next

    'TO CLEAR CHART AND RELOAD IT
    Chart1.Titles.Clear()
    Chart1.Series.Clear()
    Chart1.ChartAreas.Clear()
    Chart1.ChartAreas.Add("AREA")
    Chart1.Series.Add("WeeklyEfficiency")
    Chart1.Series.Add("TARGET")
    Chart1.Titles.Add("ROUTE EFFICIENCY")
    Chart1.Series("TARGET").ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line

    With Chart1.Titles(0)
        .Font = New Font("TAHOMA", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
    End With

    With Chart1.ChartAreas(0)
        '.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
        .AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
        .AxisX.Title = "WEEKS"
        .AxisY.Title = "EFFICIENCY"
        .AxisX.Minimum = 0
        .AxisX.Maximum = 53
        .AxisY.Minimum = 0
        .AxisX.Interval = 1
        .AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = Format(0, "0%")
   End With

   With Chart1.Series(0)
        .Font = New Font(Me.Font.Name, 7, FontStyle.Regular)
        .SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = False
        .LabelAngle = -90
        .Label = "#VAL{P}"
        .IsValueShownAsLabel = True
        .Name = "WeeklyEfficiency"
        .ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
        .LabelToolTip = Enabled
        .ToolTip = "WEEK #VALX" & vbNewLine & "#VAL{P}"
        .BorderColor = Color.Black
        .LabelForeColor = Color.Transparent
        Dim area As String = cbArea.Text
        Select Case area
            Case "BC_PICKUP"
                .Color = Color.Blue
            Case "BC_DELIVERY"
                .Color = Color.Blue
            Case "RAW"
                .Color = Color.LimeGreen
            Case "RTV"
                .Color = Color.Yellow
           Case Else
                .Color = Color.Black
        End Select
        'LOAD DATA POINTS
        With .Points
            .AddXY(0, 0)
            .AddXY(1, LblWkEff1.Text)
            .AddXY(2, LblWkEff2.Text)
            .AddXY(3, LblWkEff3.Text)
            .AddXY(4, LblWkEff4.Text)
            .AddXY(5, LblWkEff5.Text)
            .AddXY(6, LblWkEff6.Text)
            .AddXY(7, LblWkEff7.Text)
            .AddXY(8, LblWkEff8.Text)
            .AddXY(9, LblWkEff9.Text)
            .AddXY(10, LblWkEff10.Text)
            .AddXY(11, LblWkEff11.Text)
            .AddXY(12, LblWkEff12.Text)
            .AddXY(13, LblWkEff13.Text)
            .AddXY(14, LblWkEff14.Text)
            .AddXY(15, LblWkEff15.Text)
            .AddXY(16, LblWkEff16.Text)
            .AddXY(17, LblWkEff17.Text)
            .AddXY(18, LblWkEff18.Text)
            .AddXY(19, LblWkEff19.Text)
            .AddXY(20, LblWkEff20.Text)
            .AddXY(21, LblWkEff21.Text)
            .AddXY(22, LblWkEff22.Text)
            .AddXY(23, LblWkEff23.Text)
            .AddXY(24, LblWkEff24.Text)
            .AddXY(25, LblWkEff25.Text)
            .AddXY(26, LblWkEff26.Text)
            .AddXY(27, LblWkEff27.Text)
            .AddXY(28, LblWkEff28.Text)
            .AddXY(29, LblWkEff29.Text)
            .AddXY(30, LblWkEff30.Text)
            .AddXY(31, LblWkEff33.Text)
            .AddXY(32, LblWkEff32.Text)
            .AddXY(33, LblWkEff33.Text)
            .AddXY(34, LblWkEff34.Text)
            .AddXY(35, LblWkEff35.Text)
            .AddXY(36, LblWkEff36.Text)
            .AddXY(37, LblWkEff37.Text)
            .AddXY(38, LblWkEff38.Text)
            .AddXY(39, LblWkEff39.Text)
            .AddXY(40, LblWkEff40.Text)
            .AddXY(41, LblWkEff41.Text)
            .AddXY(42, LblWkEff42.Text)
            .AddXY(43, LblWkEff43.Text)
            .AddXY(44, LblWkEff44.Text)
            .AddXY(45, LblWkEff45.Text)
            .AddXY(46, LblWkEff46.Text)
            .AddXY(47, LblWkEff47.Text)
            .AddXY(48, LblWkEff48.Text)
            .AddXY(49, LblWkEff49.Text)
            .AddXY(50, LblWkEff50.Text)
            .AddXY(51, LblWkEff51.Text)
            .AddXY(52, LblWkEff52.Text)
            .AddXY(53, 0)
        End With
    End With

    With Chart1.Series("TARGET")
        .Name = "TARGET"
        .ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
        .Color = Color.Red
        .BorderWidth = 3
        With .Points
            .AddXY(0, 1)
            .AddXY(1, 1)
            .AddXY(2, 1)
            .AddXY(3, 1)
            .AddXY(4, 1)
            .AddXY(5, 1)
            .AddXY(6, 1)
            .AddXY(7, 1)
            .AddXY(8, 1)
            .AddXY(9, 1)
            .AddXY(10, 1)
            .AddXY(11, 1)
            .AddXY(12, 1)
            .AddXY(13, 1)
            .AddXY(14, 1)
            .AddXY(15, 1)
            .AddXY(16, 1)
            .AddXY(17, 1)
            .AddXY(18, 1)
            .AddXY(19, 1)
            .AddXY(20, 1)
            .AddXY(21, 1)
            .AddXY(22, 1)
            .AddXY(23, 1)
            .AddXY(24, 1)
            .AddXY(25, 1)
            .AddXY(26, 1)
            .AddXY(27, 1)
            .AddXY(28, 1)
            .AddXY(29, 1)
            .AddXY(30, 1)
            .AddXY(31, 1)
            .AddXY(32, 1)
            .AddXY(33, 1)
            .AddXY(34, 1)
            .AddXY(35, 1)
            .AddXY(36, 1)
            .AddXY(37, 1)
            .AddXY(38, 1)
            .AddXY(39, 1)
            .AddXY(40, 1)
            .AddXY(41, 1)
            .AddXY(42, 1)
            .AddXY(43, 1)
            .AddXY(44, 1)
            .AddXY(45, 1)
            .AddXY(46, 1)
            .AddXY(47, 1)
            .AddXY(48, 1)
            .AddXY(49, 1)
            .AddXY(50, 1)
            .AddXY(51, 1)
            .AddXY(52, 1)
            .AddXY(53, 1)
        End With
    End With

    'MAKE ONTIME CHART
    '______________________________________________________________________________()
    'TO CLEAR CHART AND RELOAD IT
    Chart2.Titles.Clear()
    Chart2.Series.Clear()
    Chart2.ChartAreas.Clear()
    Chart2.ChartAreas.Add("AREA")
    Chart2.Series.Add("WeeklyEfficiency")
    Chart2.Series.Add("TARGET")
    Chart2.Titles.Add("ON TIME EFFICIENCY")

    With Chart2.Titles(0)
        .Font = New Font("TAHOMA", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
    End With

    With Chart2.ChartAreas(0)
        '.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
        .AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
        .AxisX.Title = "WEEKS"
        .AxisY.Title = "EFFICIENCY"
        .AxisX.Minimum = 0
        .AxisX.Maximum = 53
        .AxisY.Minimum = 0
        .AxisX.Interval = 1
        .AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = Format(0, "0%")
    End With

    With Chart2.Series(0)
        .Font = New Font(Me.Font.Name, 7, FontStyle.Regular)
        .SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = False
        .LabelAngle = -90
        .Label = "#VAL{P}"
        .IsValueShownAsLabel = True
        .Name = "WeeklyEfficiency"
        .ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
        .LabelToolTip = Enabled
        .ToolTip = "WEEK #VALX" & vbNewLine & "#VAL{P}"
        .BorderColor = Color.Black
        .LabelForeColor = Color.Transparent
        Dim area As String = cbArea.Text
        Select Case area
            Case "BC_PICKUP"
                .Color = Color.Blue
            Case "BC_DELIVERY"
                .Color = Color.Blue
            Case "RAW"
                .Color = Color.LimeGreen
            Case "RTV"
                .Color = Color.Yellow
            Case Else
                .Color = Color.Black
        End Select
        'LOAD DATA POINTS
        .Points.AddXY(0, 0)
        .Points.AddXY(1, lblDeliveryStat1.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(2, lblDeliveryStat2.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(3, lblDeliveryStat3.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(4, lblDeliveryStat4.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(5, lblDeliveryStat5.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(6, lblDeliveryStat6.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(7, lblDeliveryStat7.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(8, lblDeliveryStat8.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(9, lblDeliveryStat9.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(10, lblDeliveryStat10.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(11, lblDeliveryStat11.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(12, lblDeliveryStat12.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(13, lblDeliveryStat13.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(14, lblDeliveryStat14.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(15, lblDeliveryStat15.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(16, lblDeliveryStat16.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(17, lblDeliveryStat17.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(18, lblDeliveryStat18.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(19, lblDeliveryStat19.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(20, lblDeliveryStat20.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(21, lblDeliveryStat21.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(22, lblDeliveryStat22.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(23, lblDeliveryStat23.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(24, lblDeliveryStat24.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(25, lblDeliveryStat25.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(26, lblDeliveryStat26.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(27, lblDeliveryStat27.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(28, lblDeliveryStat28.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(29, lblDeliveryStat29.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(30, lblDeliveryStat30.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(31, lblDeliveryStat33.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(32, lblDeliveryStat32.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(33, lblDeliveryStat33.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(34, lblDeliveryStat34.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(35, lblDeliveryStat35.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(36, lblDeliveryStat36.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(37, lblDeliveryStat37.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(38, lblDeliveryStat38.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(39, lblDeliveryStat39.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(40, lblDeliveryStat40.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(41, lblDeliveryStat41.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(42, lblDeliveryStat42.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(43, lblDeliveryStat43.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(44, lblDeliveryStat44.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(45, lblDeliveryStat45.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(46, lblDeliveryStat46.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(47, lblDeliveryStat47.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(48, lblDeliveryStat48.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(49, lblDeliveryStat49.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(50, lblDeliveryStat50.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(51, lblDeliveryStat51.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(52, lblDeliveryStat52.Text)
        .Points.AddXY(53, 0)
    End With

    With Chart2.Series("TARGET")
        .Name = "TARGET"
        .ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
        .Color = Color.Red
        .BorderWidth = 3
        With .Points
            .AddXY(0, 1)
            .AddXY(1, 1)
            .AddXY(2, 1)
            .AddXY(3, 1)
            .AddXY(4, 1)
            .AddXY(5, 1)
            .AddXY(6, 1)
            .AddXY(7, 1)
            .AddXY(8, 1)
            .AddXY(9, 1)
            .AddXY(10, 1)
            .AddXY(11, 1)
            .AddXY(12, 1)
            .AddXY(13, 1)
            .AddXY(14, 1)
            .AddXY(15, 1)
            .AddXY(16, 1)
            .AddXY(17, 1)
            .AddXY(18, 1)
            .AddXY(19, 1)
            .AddXY(20, 1)
            .AddXY(21, 1)
            .AddXY(22, 1)
            .AddXY(23, 1)
            .AddXY(24, 1)
            .AddXY(25, 1)
            .AddXY(26, 1)
            .AddXY(27, 1)
            .AddXY(28, 1)
            .AddXY(29, 1)
            .AddXY(30, 1)
            .AddXY(31, 1)
            .AddXY(32, 1)
            .AddXY(33, 1)
            .AddXY(34, 1)
            .AddXY(35, 1)
            .AddXY(36, 1)
            .AddXY(37, 1)
            .AddXY(38, 1)
            .AddXY(39, 1)
            .AddXY(40, 1)
            .AddXY(41, 1)
            .AddXY(42, 1)
            .AddXY(43, 1)
            .AddXY(44, 1)
            .AddXY(45, 1)
            .AddXY(46, 1)
            .AddXY(47, 1)
            .AddXY(48, 1)
            .AddXY(49, 1)
            .AddXY(50, 1)
            .AddXY(51, 1)
            .AddXY(52, 1)
            .AddXY(53, 1)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `AddXY(53, 1)` did you type all of that by hand? Use a loop.

Comment: Please tag your questions with the programming language you are using (other than SQL).

Comment: Johnbot, I added the query.

Comment: This is likely better suited for the Code Review site.

Comment: If you perform an SQL query from whatever tool your DBMS provides (e.g. SQL Server Management Studio if you are using MS SQL Server), how long does that take? That would show you where improvements might be made.

Comment: Issuing 104 queries to load labels on one form... Are these labels similar in meaning? Consider using one query that returns 104 results instead, chances are you will make it 100 times faster.

Comment: Andrew, I'm using SQL Server MGMT Studio. When the program starts, the code that I pasted in my question is performed. I've timed it at 5 seconds. That's way too long.

Neolisk, yes; I am issuing 104 queries to load labels, on one form. As far as all 104 labels, on the form, containing similar meaning; they are similar in that they are all each weeks and strings, other than that the (Name) and Text are different. 

How would I go about issuing one query to return all 104 results? I had tried that but I nested 104 queires in the SQL statement. I saw no improvement. perhaps I didn't do it right.

Comment: @Joseph.Scott.Garza (1) If you start your comment with @NameOfPerson then we get notified that you have replied. (2) If you surround your chart updates with, e.g. `Chart1.SuspendLayout()` and `Chart1.ResumeLayout()` then it won't be redrawing it for every change. That should speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a Caller Id Program I'm developing When the user was bringing back more than a couple of hundred call records it was taking forever

My approach was to only query the DB once at the beginning, Then Use linq on the data Set to bring back in the individual pieces of data

Ian

```
Private Sub LoadWeeklyStats()
'Get Global DataSource Here 
For i As Integer = 0 To 51
    Dim LabelWkEff As String = "LblWkEff" + (i + 1).ToString
    Dim myArray1 As Array = Controls.Find(LabelWkEff, False)
    Dim myControl1 As Label = myArray1(0)
    myControl1.Text = RESULT1
    'AND
    Dim LabelDeliveryStat As String = "lblDeliveryStat" + (i + 1).ToString
    Dim myArray2 As Array = Controls.Find(LabelDeliveryStat, False)
    Dim myControl2 As Label = myArray2(0)
    myControl2.Text = RESULT2
    'COUNTER
    Week(i + 1)
Next
```